# Amazon ELB Header trouble

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

i have a EC2 ELB with two instances on it.
Both instances always redirect traffic to different URL based on the user agent and other things with a HTTP 302 code.
The problem is that ELB always send the request to both instances because I think that always expects a HTTP 200 response code. I am correct?
Is there any way to fix this?
The health check is OK and works fine on the root of the site. It get's a HTTP 200 code, but when I want to use the application thar redirect the user, it fails and sends the request to both instances.

Can anoyone help me?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not correct. Other than the health check the ELB does not care what the response code from the instances is. The ELB also does not send a single request to both instances.